# ¿Como cargo múltiples JPanels en un solo JFrame? - JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Quiero hacer un programa que use múltiples paneles en un solo JFrame para evitar que se creen nuevas ventanas (múltiples JFrames) ya que seria muy incomodo para el usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu proyecto deberas tener un jfram principal 
Con un menu  de donde llamaras los jpanels
Al dar click con instancias cada jpanel

Lo puedes hacer desede el modo grafico la creacion del jpanel
 Y lo llamarias asi

Ejemplo

> private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
>   {
>
> ```
>  Jpanel1.setVisible(true);     }
> ```